# How to get the content of the content attribute for a meta tag with js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the content of the content attribute of a meta tag on a webpage, I want my code to find all the metatags on a given webpage and I want the code to then read what's inside the content attribute and return that as a readable string. However, I don't want to specify any name or property attributes for the meta tag because I want the code to pick up all the content of all the meta tags.

I started like this:

```
var meta = $(document).find("meta[content]").text();
```

But this just returns an empty value, probably because it can't really find the content because I haven't specified it well. I'm new to this, please help me! :D

Thanks and may the force be with you!

Comment: Sure: <meta name="SEO test" content="Dit is de meta voor de seo test FLAMINGO."/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text()` method returns the text content within an element. This is not correct when trying to retrieve information from a `meta` element, as they have no text.

instead, to retrieve the value of the `content` attribute, use `attr()`:

```
var content = $('meta[content]').attr('content');
```

Comment: I tried this too, but it won't output a readable string it will just give me something like [object, object]

Comment: That's not possible as `attr()` returns a string. Could you please update your question to show the HTML.

Comment: Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kgaaqp0k/. Note that you may need to make the selector more specific if you have multiple `meta` tags with a `content` attribute, as I had to with the fiddle.

Comment: Yes but you keep missing the big problem, which is that i DO NOT want to specify the name property because I want the code to be flexible and apply to all meta tags.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out! I will tick the question in 3 minutes when I can! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE HELP!!!!!! :D!!!

Answer (score 0):

something like below code to get `metatag` content

```
var author = $('meta[name=author]').attr("content");
```

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned I want to leave out the name part, because the code needs to be flexible on all meta tags, not just the specified one.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is as below

```
<head>
  <meta id="dirName" name="dirName" content="project name" />
</head>
```

The Jquery code will be

```
var dirPath= $('#dirName').attr('content');
console.log(dirPath);
```